# Custom ConfigureOptions is not changing set options when Configure is called

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8, microsoft.extensions.configuration

I'm trying to create a custom `ConfigureOptions` class implementing `IConfigureNamedOptions` in .NET 4.8.

Here is the implementation

```
public class ConfigureAppSettings : IConfigureNamedOptions<AppOptions>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public ConfigureAppSettings()
    {
        configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().BuildAdapterConfiguration("appsettings.json");
    }

    public void Configure(AppOptions options)
    {
        Configure(nameof(AppOptions), options);
    }

    public void Configure(string name, AppOptions options)
    {
        IOptions<AppOptions> configurationOptions = Options.Create(configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppOptions)).Get<AppOptions>());
        options = configurationOptions.Value;
    }
}
```

When configuring the dependency injection container the `services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureAppSettings>();` is called.

But then, when I want to use `IOptionsSnapshot<AppOptions>`, `Value` is `null`.

While debugging `options` is set inside the `Configure` method but when exists it, `options` reference is not preserved and is `null`.

How can I get the value set in `Configure` method?

Side note: I need this implementation because on `Configure` method I also need to call an HTTP service to the some `options` properties.

Comment: How about showing your appsettings file?  I reckon you don't have a section called "AppOptions" in the root of the json.

Comment: There is a section `AppOptions` because `Options.Create(configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppOptions)).Get<AppOptions>());` returns the expected properties from `appsettings.json`. The problem is that `options` parameter from `Configure` method doesn't "persist" the changes.

Comment: What you are trying to do here is _replacing_ the object reference to `AppOptions options`. This does not work since the `options` parameter is not a `ref` parameter. Therefore, you should also get a warning `IDE0059 Unneccessary assignment of a value to 'options'`. You get the warning because the assignment has no effect. I am looking at the same task: to replace the entire `options` object in Configure()` without manually replacing every single object property. Hopefully, there is someone who knows a better way.